# Is there another way to set initial values on a Kendo virtualized mutliselect widget?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a kendo multi-select widget that is bound to a lot of data, to handle this I have virtualized the widget and put the stress onto the server.

I'm trying to select some initial data via a javascript function that passes an array of Ids.  It works well **only if** the data that's being selected is on the first paged result set of the widget, if any of the Ids are further in then they are not selected and I need to fix it.

Here is the code for my widget:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
.Name("Cars")
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("Id")
.Placeholder("Select cars...")
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.DataSource(source => { source
    .Custom()
    .ServerFiltering(true)
    .Events(e => e.Error("errorHandler"))
    .ServerPaging(true)
    .PageSize(80)
    .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
    .Transport(transport => {
        transport.Read("GetData", "Positions");
    })
    .Schema(schema => { schema
        .Data("Data")
        .Total("Total")
        .Errors("Errors");
    });
}))
```

The data is received from the `GetData` Method of the Positions controller which is tied to my cars repository.

**GetData**

```
public JsonResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get().OrderBy(n => n.Name);
    var results = vessel.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(results);
}
```

Here is my function that runs after user input (button).  I've added a sample array to show you what's passed in.

**InitialSelection**

```
function initialSelection(filter) {
    //filter is: "6544","4880","6545","6548"
    var carSelection = $("#Cars").data("kendoMultiSelect");    
    var filterArray = filter.split(',').map(Number);

    if (filterArray.length > 0) {
        console.log(filterArray)
        carSelection.value(filterArray);
    } else {
        carSelection.value();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to make an initial selection of data than what I'm doing with the above javascript?  As I said, if the ids are not on the first page of results that are returned, they are not selected which is frustrating.

Comment: If you have some values why not pass those id's back to the server on the initial call and include them in the first page of results?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidShorthose can you give an example of how that would be possible just so I'm clear on what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change the read declaration to something like this:

```
 .Transport(transport => {
        transport.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Positions").Data("intialvalues"));
    })
```

Then add a function for the `initialvalues` data object like:

```
function inititalvalues(){
    var filterArray = filter.split(',').map(Number);

if(filterArray === undefined || filterArray === null || filterArray.length <= 0) 
{
    filterArray = []
}
 return {filterValues: filterArray}; 
}
```

then in your read method on your controller you add the following:

```
 public JsonResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<int> filterValues)
        {

            if (filterValues.Count > 0 && request.Page == 1)
            {
                  ..get the first page  minus how many filterValues you have to inject the selected Items at the top of the list...


            }
            else if (filterValues.Count > 0 && request.Page > 1)
            {
                 ..get the page you need and remove any selected items from the page as they will be at the top...
            }
            else
            {
                 ..just get everything as normal as nothing should be selected at this stage.
            }

            return your paged resultset back...
        }
```

hopefully that gives you a starting point.